# Delphi properties with single getter and setter

Tags: delphi, properties, attributes, rtti

I'm trying to implement a configuration file class wrapper and would be easier using a single function to get and a single function to set values to properties.

The code bellow is a minimum version of what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help will be welcome.

```
unit Config;

interface

uses Rtti;

type
  Group = class(TCustomAttribute)
  strict private
    FName: string;

  public
    constructor Create(const Name: string);

    property Name: string read FName;
  end;

  IConfig = class
  protected
    function GetString: string;
    procedure SetString(const Value: string);
  end;

  TConfig = class(IConfig)
  public
    [Group('Person')]
    property Name: string read GetString write SetString;
    [Group('Person')]
    property City: string read GetString write SetString;
  end;

implementation

{ Group }

constructor Group.Create(const Name: string);
begin
  FName := Name;
end;

{ IConfig }

function IConfig.GetString: string;
begin
  // Here I would need the following from the property that call this function:
  // * Property name
  // * Property attribute name

  // This kind of code will not work, because it loop through all available properties
  (*
    var
      ctx: TRttiContext;
      objType: TRttiType;
      Prop: TRttiProperty;
    begin
      ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
      objType := ctx.GetType(Obj.ClassInfo);
      for Prop in objType.GetProperties do begin
        if Prop.GetClassType is TClassBase then
          // do something special with base class properties
        else
          // standard functionality on all other properties
      end;
    end;
  *)
end;

procedure IConfig.SetString(const Value: string);
begin
  // Need the same as above
end;

end.
```

Comment: Do you want do to something like this? http://robstechcorner.blogspot.be/2009/10/ini-persistence-rtti-way.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Property getters and setters do not know which property is calling them.  The only way for a shared getter/setter to know that is to use the `index` specifier, eg:

```
unit Config;

interface

uses Rtti;

type
  Group = class(TCustomAttribute)
  strict private
    FName: string;

  public
    constructor Create(const Name: string);

    property Name: string read FName;
  end;

  IConfig = class
  protected
    function GetString(Index: Integer): string;
    procedure SetString(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
  end;

  TConfig = class(IConfig)
  public
    [Group('Person')]
    property Name: string index 0 read GetString write SetString;
    [Group('Person')]
    property City: string index 1 read GetString write SetString;
  end;

implementation

{ Group }

constructor Group.Create(const Name: string);
begin
  FName := Name;
end;

{ IConfig }

function IConfig.GetString(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  case Index of
    0: begin // Name
    ...
    end;
    1: begin // City
      ...
    end;
    ...
  end;
end;

procedure IConfig.SetString(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
begin
  // same as above
end;

end.
```

If the getter/setter needs to know the property name, you can use RTTI to find the property that has the corresponding `index` value, and if found then you would also have access to its attributes, eg:

```
function GetPropNameAndGroup(Cls: TClass; PropIndex: Integer; var PropName, GroupName: String): Boolean;
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
  Attr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  PropName := '';
  GroupName := '';
  Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  for Prop in Ctx.GetType(Cls).GetProperties do
  begin
    if (Prop as TRttiInstanceProperty).Index = PropIndex then
    begin
      PropName := Prop.Name;
      for Attr in Prop.GetAttributes do
      begin
        if Attr is Group then
        begin
          GroupName := Group(Attr).Name;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  Result := (PropName <> '') and (GroupName <> '');
end;

function IConfig.GetString(Index: Integer): string;
var
  PropName, GroupName: string;
begin
  if GetPropNameAndGroup(ClassType, Index, PropName, GroupName) then
  begin
    //...
  end;
end;

procedure IConfig.SetString(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
var
  PropName, GroupName: string;
begin
  if GetPropNameAndGroup(ClassType, Index, PropName, GroupName) then
  begin
    //...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A property getter or setter has no way to determine which property was accessed that led to the getter or setter being called.

The corollary to that statement is that what you are asking to do is impossible.

As to how to solve your underlying problem, I would not care to speculate on that in too much detail. It is plausible that [property index access specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Index_Specifiers) could be useful to you. But without knowledge of the actual problem you face, I don't feel qualified to go into more detail.

Comment: That is incorrect. In Delphi you can specify an `Index` specifier for a property which becomes an extra parameter to getters and setters.

Comment: @Lasse That is true. But the question does not ask about indexed properties.

Comment: I understood it to be just that since he asks how to add a single getter and a setter to handle the properties.

Comment: @Lasse No he wants to find the property by some magic, then read the attribute attached to the property, and then access a value based on that attribute.

Comment: In fact he did not ask how to do this with RTTI and attributes, it is just inside the source and shows what he had tried so far.

Comment: @Sir So what was asked. Did I not understand? What is the underlying problem?